# If $a,b \in P \subset \text{field }F$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $na > b$.

Tags: field-theory

> If $a,b \in P$ which is the positive cone of the ordered field $F$, show that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\underbrace{a+a+ \ldots + a}_{n \text{ times}} > b$.

For full context, this is the question
[image]

This problem is trivial in the real numbers, but how to show it in an arbitary ordered field? This is what I have tried.

If $a>b$, then we are done, so suppose $a<b$. Then let's suppose that for all $n$, $na<b$. Since $b^{-1} \in P$, we can mutiply through to get $nab^{-1}<u \implies ab^{-1}<u/n$, but this doesn't work, since $u \in F$.

Intuitively I know that I should choose an $n$ such that $n>b/a$, but since $b/a \in F$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there's no way to compare them.

If we want to use the least upper bound property of a field, doesn't that require the field to be Archimedean (edit: complete)? But we can't make that assumption here, so proofs like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101891/least-upper-bound-property-implies-that-the-orderered-field-in-question-is-archi) wouldn't work.

Hints appreciated.

Comment: More precisely, $(P\subset\mathbb F\;\land\;n\notin\mathbb F)\implies n\notin P$.

Comment: Completness in this context is not what you might thought, that every Cauchy sequence is convergent. Completness here means that the field has the least upper bound property.

Comment: Oh man I missed the completeness part. I was about to say that I feel like we need extra information beyond just an ordered field.

Comment: I also think more information is needed. I came across several answers that used the fact of completeness to prove this. I'll ask my professor about this.